# The condition for an algebraic expression to be square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My textbook on pre-college Algebra mentions the following fact:

> We have the expression $y^2(h^2-ab)+2y(gh-af)+g^2-ac$. The condition for this expression to be a perfect square is if we have $(2(gh-af))^2=4(h^2-ab)(g^2-ac)$.

Now I understand that if this condition is satisfied, then the expression is a perfect square (treating the expression as a quadratic in $y$). However, is this really the **only** condition for the expression to be a square? I mean even if this expression can only be written as $p(y-q)(y-r)$, where $q\neq r$, does this **prove** that the expression cannot be a square?

Comment: You might want to read up on the Unique Factorization Theorem, as it applies to polynomials with coefficients in a field.

Comment: @GerryMyerson- Thanks that answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

If the expression is a perfect square, then it factors as $(y-r)^2=(y-r)(y-r)$, so that the two roots of the given quadratic are the same. Using the quadratic formula, what does the fact that the two roots are the same tell you about the quantity $(2(gh-af))^2-4(h^2-ab)(g^2-ac)$?

Comment: I think you have completely misunderstood the question. I know that this condition implies that the expression is a square. MHy question is: is this the **only** possible condition for the expression to be a square?

Comment: No, I correctly understood the question, and my response is of the form "If the expression is a square, then...", which will, if carried through, prove what you want to prove.